# pg_dump: [archiver (db)] query failed: ERROR: permission denied for relation abouts

Tags: ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to dump my pg db but got these errors please suggest

```
pg_dump: [archiver (db)] query failed: ERROR:  permission denied for relation abouts
pg_dump: [archiver (db)] query was: LOCK TABLE public.abouts IN ACCESS SHARE MODE
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The user which you're performing your `pg_dump` as doesn't have permissions on the public schema.

Add permissions if allowed:

```
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA public TO <user>;
GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO <user>;
```

Also if there is any sequence, you should access to them, too:

```
GRANT SELECT, USAGE ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA public TO <user>;
```

Comment: `GRANT SELECT ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA public TO <user>;` might also be necessary.

Comment: 1) `[ sudo ] su postgres`

2) `psql`

3) `GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA public TO <user>;`

4) `GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO <user>;`

Answer (score 17):

This can be a common error, when using a `ROLE` (user) that could not open the objects to dump them.

Like said before, you can grant to the specific schema that you want to dump, or even use a `ROLE` with `SUPERUSER` attribute.

Note that when you are dealing with some cloud database providers, like AWS/RDS you will not receive a user with the `SUPERUSER` attribute, so you will need to manage to make sure that the one used to dump will have all access needed.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-grant.html will show how give `GRANT` to many objects on your database, but also remember that when restoring you will need to create the database first. Only if you are using `pg_dumpall` that is not necessary, but you also need to dump the `ROLES`.

Comment: I am using ROLE 'postgres' and I get this error, so I do not trust this answer.

Comment: @user10664542: The ROLE 'postgres' may not necessarily be a real superuser, which has access to all objects. It may be necessary even using 'postgres' role to check the permissions that you have.  When connected with `psql` you can use \du.

Answer (score 15):

Change the permission to the user: login as sudo user by using following cmd

```
sudo -u postgres psql
```

Alter the user role

```
alter role <user-name> superuser;
```