# Export postgres user list to migrate to a new version on GCP

Tags: google-cloud-sql

I need to migrate my postgres database to a newer version. For that, I do the dump and restore, without problems. However, users from one instance are not copied to another, as was the case with the dump_all command using local postgres.
How do I export these users to a new installation, thus allowing to migrate my database to a newer version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This article](https://medium.com/google-cloud/migrate-users-with-credentials-from-cloudsql-to-another-instance-or-alloydb-for-postgresql-e377a222d3f8) explains a workaround for Google Cloud for Postgres.

Basically you enable access to the pg_shadow table for the user you login with, e.g. "postgres", by setting the database flag `cloudsql.pg_shadow_select_role`, then run this query to create a dynamic query to re-create the users with the existing hashed passwords:

```
SELECT 'CREATE ROLE "'|| usename ||'" NOINHERIT LOGIN PASSWORD '''|| passwd ||''';' 
FROM pg_shadow 
WHERE usename <> 'postgres' AND usename not ilike 'cloud%' ORDER BY usename ASC
```

What this can't do is upgrade passwords from md5 to SCRAM automatically. You would have to enter all the passwords manually to do that.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Cloud Sql upgrade documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/upgrade-db#migrating) you should provide user details manually in a new instance, which implies that tables containing information on users are not getting propagated during the dump and restore.

Comment: Thanks Emil. I just filled a issue for it: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/148423505