# Import of pg_dump custom format from Google Cloud SQL error `pg_restore: [custom archiver] unrecognized data block type (151) while searching archive`

Tags: google-cloud-sql

I want to use `pg_dump` to create a custom format dump (`--format=custom`) from Google Cloud SQL, then import that into my local database for development. My attempts to import the dump result in the error:

`pg_restore: [custom archiver] unrecognized data block type (151) while searching archive`

My DuckDuckGo-fu yields no relevant results. There is a [similar post for exporting in plain format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59760407/how-do-i-dump-a-google-cloud-sql-for-postgresql-db-to-import-back-into-a-regular), but plain format is about 10 times the size of a custom archive format. When I import a plain SQL file, it is successful.

There is documentation for doing the reverse, [Exporting and importing using pg_dump and pg_restore](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/import-export/import-export-dmp?authuser=1), but this is not what I want to do.

Finally, I am able to import custom archives in other projects I work on, including one on AWS and another on Digital Ocean, so I wonder what I'm doing wrong on Google Cloud SQL.

### Edit

Here's the `pg_dump` command.

`pg_dump --format=c --no-owner --no-acl --file="~/projects/project/backups/project-custom.sqlc" --dbname=project --schema='public'`

I have no clue how to do a `pg_restore` of this.

Comment: Could you please share the commands that you are using with `pg_dump` and `pg_restore`?

Comment: @Sergi I don't have a valid `pg_restore` for this environment, but I at least provided the typical `pg_dump` command that I use and which works on other environments.