# How to create local clone of a GCP Cloud SQL export for PostgresQL

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I have exported a database as a SQL file in Google Cloud Platform Cloud SQL Postgres Database using their GUI wizard. I want to import the data from the dump into my local PostgresQL installation. I tried using PgAdmin4 with various settings but kept failing. I then tried the following command which retrieved the data but most of the relationships are gone.

```
psql -f "SQLFile.sql" --host "localhost" --port "5432" --username "dbusername" "myDBName"
```

How can I create a local clone of my Cloud SQL db?

Comment: Look inside SQLFile.sql.  Does it contain those missing tables, or were they missing from the dump file as well?

Comment: @jjanes sql file contains everything I am posting what my issue was as an answer if anyone else needs it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posting an answer for anyone else who needs this. The following was performed on a Windows 10 machine.

1. Export from Cloud SQL using the GCP console GUI. This will save it to a cloud storage bucket and you can download it from GCS bucket.
2. On local machine - remove any database with the same name as the one you want to import . Then create a fresh database with the same name as the one you want to import. (in my case this was the issue)
3. In terminal go to your PostgreSQL `bin` folder. Example:

```
cd “C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13\bin
```

4. Then run the following command - replacing values as per your needs.

```
psql -f "<full-path-to-downloaded-sql-file>" --host "localhost" --port "5432" --username "<local-postgres-username>" "<db-name-to-import>”
```

5. You may need to grant privileges to users on tables. This can be done using the grant wizard in [pgAdmin 4](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/development/grant_wizard.html) or as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15520361/permission-denied-for-relation).

Comment: It was helpful for me (y)